# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '1064'

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I'm busy on rewriting my registration function. And suddently, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '1064' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\app\classes\users.class.php:123 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\index.php(5): users->register() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zephryte\app\classes\users.class.php on line 123
```

The only thing is, I don't know what a `1064` is... Is there a list availible on the internet with these codes and their meaning? I'll also provide some of my code:

```
    $query = $this->db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ht_users VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");//120
    if($this->db->conn->errno)//121
    {//122
         throw new Exception($this->db->conn->errno);//123
    }//124
```

Did I make any real simple mistakes? And am I not seeing the forest through the trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket:

```
$query = $this->db->conn->prepare
("INSERT INTO ht_users VALUES 
('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");//120
                                                                     ^ that one
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what database system you're using, but that is probably the error code from your database and you can generally look up online what they mean, although looking in the database's log file might be easier.

Comment: ETA: You don't close the ')' in the query, that's most likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your system use MySQL, message '1064' means " Error in SQL syntax".